# How Do I Install SDL 2.0 for Development On Debian?

Tags: linux, debian, sdl, sdl-2

I have been looking into OpenGL development recently and after watching a tutorial, noticed I was unable to compile my code. References that seem to be two features added specifically in SDL 2.0 are undefined according to Eclipse. I tried searching for a way to install SDL 2.0 on Debian (more specifically I am using `#!` but it is close enough to Debian that a fix on Debian will work).

The way I keep finding is to type into the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install libsdl2-dev
```

This package is not found by aptitude. Can anyone tell me how to install SDL 2.0 on Debian?

Comment: Looks like there's [a package (`libsdl2-dev`)](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy-backports/libsdl2-dev) in [`wheezy-backports`](http://backports.debian.org/Instructions/#index2h2).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok. Thank you to genpfault for telling me that libsdl2-dev was on backports! I would have never figured it out, especially because I have never used backports before!

For those of you stuck on this problem go to the following link if you do not know how to use backports:

http://backports.debian.org/Instructions/

Once you have setup backports, open up your terminal and run the following if you are using wheezy:

```
apt-get -t wheezy-backports install "package"
```

For other versions of Debian, I think you just need to put the name of your operating system version in the above code where I put "wheezy".

Remember in your IDE or in your terminal to compile with SDL2 instead of SDL. Best of luck!

Comment: The big problem for me is the question "Do I want to use backports?" There's just too much information and not enough time, to work out whether it would be "safe" or "stable".